# MySQL easier way to call all values rather calling them individually in INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to call all values in an INNER JOIN rather calling them individually?

```
SELECT l.*, p.pageID AS pageID, p.pageType AS pageType, p.pageTitle AS pageTitle ..... FROM languages l INNER JOIN pages p ON ....
```

Is this the only way to get records from table 'pages' and use them in my fetch records?

Answer (score 1):

use as **Akam** specified

```
SELECT l.*, p.* ..... FROM languages l INNER JOIN pages p ON ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT l.*, p.* FROM languages l INNER JOIN pages p ON ...
```

Except if `languages` and `pages` has fields of duplicated names, `pages` field will overwrite the `languages` one. You may need this in that case:

```
SELECT l.*, p.*, l.some_field as some_alias FROM languages l INNER JOIN pages p ON ...
```